# Twillio Verify - how to send unique codes each call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

every time I call api to get code, it gives me the same code number.
I tried to update status to from “pending” to “cancelled”, it did not help at all.
Twillio send me code every time I ask them. but they send me THE SAME CODE EVERY TIME. I want UNIQUE CODE EVERY TIME.

They also provide “Custom codes feature”, but they have poor documentation and it’s unclear whether I would achieve unique codes with it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the requirement for a unique code each time to the same destination number?

The verify code will be the same for 10 minutes, then it will change.

You can find more details [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/developer-best-practices#token-validity-period).

Answer (score 0):

Check how Whatsapp phone verification works.
I want "Resend a new code" feature, don't want to wait 10 seconds